# T-SQL CASE Check for youngest date and then against the other values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, datetime, case

EDIT: Remade the whole question. Brought it the wrong way the first time.

The **Results** should be like:

```
MachineName | OrderNo | TaskID | Code | NettoProd | BrutoProd | DiffProd
=========================================================================
F1            123456    101      O      100000      125000      25000
F1            123456    102      P8     1000000     1250000     250000
F1            123456    103      P1     10000       12500       2500
F1            123456    104      P4     100000      125000      25000
```

The `JobSummary` has the following columns:

```
StartDate 
TaskID
```

The `Route` has the following columns:

```
OrderNo 
TaskID
```

The `Resource` holds the data about the machines

```
MachineID
```

I already added the part of Kyle Gobel, which was the correct answer, if I had provided all details in the first place.

What I would like to accomplish is to show an `O` when it's the first `taskID` of the tasks linked to one `OrderNo` based on the `StartDate`, which is a `DateTime` field in the table.

If it's impossible to check for both `Route.No` and `JobSummary.StarDate` in one `CASE` statement, then a separate column for both will do too.

**Query**

```
SELECT Resource.DESCRIPTION AS MachineName
    ,Route.OrderNo
    ,Route.TaskID
    ,CASE
        WHEN JobSummary.StartDate = (SELECT MIN(cr.StartDate) FROM JobSummary cr) THEN 'O'
        WHEN Route.No = 1 OR Route.No = 2 THEN 'P1'
        WHEN Route.No = 4 THEN 'P4'
        WHEN Route.No >= 8 THEN 'P8'
        ELSE '*FP*'
    END AS Code
    ,JobSummary.GoodProd As NettoProd
    ,JobSummary.GoodProd + JobSummary.SetupProd + JobSummary.WasteProd As BrutoProd
    ,(JobSummary.SetupProd + JobSummary.WasteProd) As DiffProd

FROM Route
JOIN Resource ON Resource.MachineID = Route.MachineID
JOIN JobSummary ON JobSummary.TaskID = Route.TaskID AND JobSummary.MachineID = Route.MachineID
```

Comment: If you could give us the query, what is not working, and the expected results, you'd more likely get a good answer.

Comment: I see no reference to either StartDate or code 'O' in the sample above; can you post a fuller example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186734.aspx) with `PARTITION BY` to identify the first record `taskID` based on its `StartDate` for an `OrderNo` like this `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Route.OrderNo ORDER BY JobSummary.StartDate ASC`

**Sample Data and Structure**

```
CREATE TABLE [JobSummary] (MachineID INT,TaskID INT,StartDate DATETIME,GoodProd NUMERIC(18,0),SetupProd NUMERIC(18,0),WasteProd NUMERIC(18,0));
CREATE TABLE [Route] (OrderNo INT,MachineID INT,TaskID INT,[No] INT);
CREATE TABLE [Resource] (MachineID INT,DESCRIPTION CHAR(2));


INSERT INTO [Resource] VALUES(1,'F1');

INSERT INTO [Route] VALUES(123456,1,101,1);
INSERT INTO [Route] VALUES(123456,1,102,9);
INSERT INTO [Route] VALUES(123456,1,103,2);
INSERT INTO [Route] VALUES(123456,1,104,4);

INSERT INTO [JobSummary] VALUES(1,101,'20150101',100000,20000,5000);
INSERT INTO [JobSummary] VALUES(1,102,'20150103',1000000,200000,50000);
INSERT INTO [JobSummary] VALUES(1,103,'20150102',10000,2000,500);
INSERT INTO [JobSummary] VALUES(1,104,'20150103',100000,20000,5000);
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT Route.No
    ,Resource.[DESCRIPTION] AS MachineName
    ,Route.OrderNo
    ,Route.TaskID
    ,JobSummary.GoodProd As NettoProd
    ,JobSummary.GoodProd + JobSummary.SetupProd + JobSummary.WasteProd As BrutoProd
    ,(JobSummary.SetupProd + JobSummary.WasteProd) As DiffProd
    ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Route.OrderNo ORDER BY JobSummary.StartDate ASC) rn
FROM Route
JOIN Resource ON Resource.MachineID = Route.MachineID
JOIN JobSummary ON JobSummary.TaskID = Route.TaskID AND JobSummary.MachineID = Route.MachineID
)
SELECT
    MachineName,
    OrderNo,
    TaskID,
    CASE
        WHEN rn = 1 THEN 'O'
        WHEN No IN (1,2) THEN 'P1'
        WHEN No = 4 THEN 'P4'
        WHEN No >= 8 THEN 'P8'
        ELSE '*FP*'
    END AS Code,
    NettoProd,
    BrutoProd,
    DiffProd
FROM CTE
ORDER BY OrderNo,TaskID
```

**Output**

```
MachineName OrderNo TaskID  Code    NettoProd   BrutoProd   DiffProd
F1  123456  101 O   100000  125000  25000
F1  123456  102 P8  1000000 1250000 250000
F1  123456  103 P1  10000   12500   2500
F1  123456  104 P4  100000  125000  25000
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78849/2)

Comment: Would have never found that out myself. Going to study the partition part on the internet. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From reading your question, you might be looking for the [min](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx) aggregate function.

```
case 
   when route.startDate = (select min(r.startdate) from table r) then 'O'
   when route.no = 1 or route.no = 2 then 'P1'
   ....
end as code
```

Answer (score 1):

Using ROW_NUMBER may be a good starting point here, but as you want to check only for the first `StartDate`, it may be a better idea to use `MIN() OVER` instead. Your posted query would need only a small change (emphasised):

```
SELECT Resource.DESCRIPTION AS MachineName
    ,Route.OrderNo
    ,Route.TaskID
    ,CASE
        WHEN JobSummary.StartDate = MIN(JobSummary.StartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY Route.OrderNo) THEN 'O'
        WHEN Route.No = 1 OR Route.No = 2 THEN 'P1'
        WHEN Route.No = 4 THEN 'P4'
        WHEN Route.No >= 8 THEN 'P8'
        ELSE '*FP*'
    END AS Code
    ,JobSummary.GoodProd As NettoProd
    ,JobSummary.GoodProd + JobSummary.SetupProd + JobSummary.WasteProd As BrutoProd
    ,(JobSummary.SetupProd + JobSummary.WasteProd) As DiffProd

FROM Route
JOIN Resource ON Resource.MachineID = Route.MachineID
JOIN JobSummary ON JobSummary.TaskID = Route.TaskID AND JobSummary.MachineID = Route.MachineID
;
```

Perhaps the PARTITION BY would need to include `Resource.DESCRIPTION` as well – hard to tell from a small example.

The above query will potentially work faster than the ROW_NUMBER method. This is because with ROW_NUMBER subsets would need to be sorted completely, whereas MIN() OVER would only look for a single value from every subset.

On the other hand, if there is a chance you will later need a special condition for a second, third etc. row, the ROW_NUMBER method would certainly be more flexible in this regard.